# Postgresql google data studio full intergration

Tags: postgresql-9.3, looker-studio

I have read about how with the Google Data Studio one is able to connect to a postgreSQL database to in turn pull data into Google's interface.  I've however not seen anywhere mentioned about a possibility of pulling data the other way, this being from Google Data Studio to the database.

Has anyone had any experience with this or can direct me in the right direction?  I advertise for several different clients and would like to have SQL functionality with each one of their account seamlessly.

Thank you in advanced,

-Iean

Comment: Can you give an use case for exactly what you are trying to do?

Answer (score 0):

Google Data Studio is for creating reports and analyzing data - there is no functionality for it to be a data source for databases. You can, when viewing a report in GDS, export the data as CSV (see https://www.branded3.com/blog/googles-data-studio-quietly-adds-data-export-functionality/)